# UnityDI does not auto-wire with default constructor

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

If the below SomeClass does not have an empty constructor then SomeClass resolves fine, but with an empty constructor it fails, so what is the right way to resolve it with Unity container?

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.Resolve<SomeClass>(); // Does not work with empty constructor

class SomeClass
{
    SomeClass()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SomeClass created");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your implemententaion of `Me` ?

Comment: What do you mean by "it fails". Do you get an exception. Then please post the StackTrace as additional information to your question.

Comment: My bad, that "Me" was a typo from previous test snippet i executed, i've fixed now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your constructor is not public. Unity does not look for private or protected constructors.